# how to type axios in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EamEn.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBtpe.png)

```
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        axios({
            method: changeMethod,
            url: changeSubmitValue,
            responseType: 'stream'
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

        });
    };
```

There is an axios typescript error as above.
The axios method changes according to the `changeMethod` state value.

**index.d.ts(48, 2): The expected type comes from property'method' which is declared here on type'AxiosRequestConfig'**

To get rid of this error, I need some help on where to type declaration in axios.

Comment: where is `changeMethod` and `changeSubmitValue` coming from?

Comment: `changeMethod` is apparently of type `string`, which is too broad. Please show us where you define that variable.

Answer (score 3):

How about fix like this union type.
Hello Korea people : )

```js
import {Method} from "axios";
...
const handleSubmit = () => {
        axios({
            method: changeMethod as Method,
            url: changeSubmitValue,
            responseType: 'stream'
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

        });
    };
```

Comment: Good Luck : ) 한국 사람 만나서 반갑네요 ㅎㅎㅎ

Comment: @suyoung please accept the answer if it solved your problem.